# django - am I hitting a memory limit with my list?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to inline my stylesheets with the following code:

views.py

```
def index(request):
latest_course_list = Course.objects.order_by('-start_date')
template = loader.get_template('index.html')
style_sheets = ""
style_sheets = addStyle(style_sheets)
ctx = {
    'latest_course_list': latest_course_list,
    'style_sheets': style_sheets,
}
return render_to_response('index.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def addStyle(style):
    style_sheets=""
    style_sheet_list = [
        "bootstrap",
        "custom-style",
        "responsive",
        "animate",
        "flexslider",
        "theme-style"
        ]

    for sheet in style_sheet_list:
        with open (DJANGO_ROOT + "/assets/css/" + sheet + ".css", "r") as myfile:
            style_sheets+=myfile.read()
        style_sheets+="\n"
    return style_sheets
```

template:

```
<style type="text/css">{{ style_sheets }}</style>
```

But it only gets down to half way through the animate.css before cutting off and just adding "..."

What limit am I hitting here? How can I solve it?

Comment: May I ask, why are you doing this? Why don't you just add the style sheets in your template?

Comment: have you tried using {{style_sheets|safe}} ?